# Pass button behaviour to partial as a parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails

#### my_view/index.html.erb

```
<%= render partial: "shared/button", locals: {title: "Foo", url:resend_verification_url, method: :put } %>
```

#### /shared/_button.html.erb

```
<%= button_to title, url, method: method || nil, class: "btn btn-primary btn-sm " %>
```

The above works, but I am trying to see if it is possible to further simplify the locals
passed to the button partial, something like:

`locals: {title: "Foo", behaviour: {resend_verification_url, method: :put}}`
and
`<%= button_to title, **behaviour , class: "btn btn-primary btn-sm " %>`

but this gives a whole load of syntax errors.

Is there a way to pass in the behaviour as one unified entity to the partial?

Comment: Your syntax error is likely because `behaviour: {resend_verification_url,...}` isn't a valid Hash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signature of `button_to` takes three parameters ([docs](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to)):

```rb
button_to(name = nil, options = nil, html_options = nil, &block)
```

- The name / label for the button
- The `options` parameter is typically a string (e.g., the output of a `_url` or `_path` helper), but can also be a hash that has the same keys generally used to configure a route in `config/routes.rb` (e.g., `:controller`, `:action`, etc.).
- The `html_options` parameter is basically a hash of everything else. There are a few special options like `:method`, `:disabled`, and `:data`, but you can also pass pure HTML attributes like `:class`.

So, you can't pass a single hash/local that incorporates both the URL and other options like in your question, since they need to be passed to `button_to` separately. If you split out the URL component, you can still do something like you are asking for the HTML options:

```rb
<%= render(partial: "shared/button", 
           locals: { title: "Foo", url: resend_verification_url, 
                     html_opts: { method: :put }) 
%>
```

And then:

```rb
<%= button_to(title, url, **html_opts, class: ...) %>
```

Comment: Yes, I guess what my question really boils down to is whether it's possible to pass multiple parameters (i.e. `options` and `html_options` in this case) to a function as a hash of arguments and for the function to be able to "destructure" it, which appears to be a "no"